# How to ignore a specific URL in Azure API Manager validate-jwt policy

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-api-management

I am trying to validate the JWT token from API Manager by following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies.

How can i ignore my /login URL from being validated for JWT Token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either add validate-jwt only to operations you want it applied to. Or add it at API level but wrap it inside `choose` policy to invoke it when `context.Request.OriginalUrl.Path != "/Login"`